# Background video with parallax effect

Tags: video, jquery-plugins, background, parallax

Is there a way to place a background video in a div container with a parallax effect? What I'm looking for is something similar to this template:

[Click here to see example](http://www.spab-rice.com/themeforest/xone/demo/index.html)

I've tried a few popular plugins I've found on the internet such as:

[BigVideo.js](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/)

[YTPlayer](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/YTPlayer.html)

[jquery.videoBG](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/)

But none of them do what I'm looking for or maybe they do but I just couldn't figure it out :(

Thank you all!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a plugin that does exactly what you need here: https://github.com/linnett/backgroundVideo

Answer (score 9):

I would create the div element with the HTML5 video first, then create the parallax scrolling.  Adding the HTML5 video and making it full-width can be as simple as:

```
<video id="myVideo" controls>
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video element.
</video>
<script>
   document.getElementById("myVideo").width=document.body.offsetWidth;
</script>
```

For the parallax, you will need to implement that separately.  The div element with the HTML5 video will just be a component of the page, just like any other layer or content section.

If you need some tutorials on creating parallax websites, my company created a list of the parallax websites available (sorted by technology: jQuery, stellar.js, and skrollr.js).
http://potentpages.com/parallax-tutorials/

The Mozilla reference for HTML5 video: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are still looking for a solution using **YTPlayer**.
Set the `containment:'self'` or `containment:'#elementID'` in the HTML constructor where `#elementID` is the ID of your `div`,`section` or parallax section where you want the video to play in background.

Refer to **YTPlayer** Wiki page [here](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki#html-constructor).

```
<div id="P1" class="player" 
     data-property="{videoURL:'http://youtu.be/l_tHTmd5pgk',containment:'self',startAt:50,mute:false,autoPlay:false,loop:false,opacity:.8}">
</div>
```